# How to drive to be the most fuel efficient

Tags: cars, transport

I saw a poster at a thruway rest stop once that said something along the lines of accelerating quickly is worse for fuel efficiency and carbon emission than idling for several hours (I don't remember the exact statistic). It made me wonder: **what ways can I drive to be more fuel efficient**? My car is 20 years old, automatic transmission, and I can't afford to buy a new car, or a hybrid car, so I have to make the best with what I have. I already drive predominantly on highways to avoid the gazillions of traffic lights in the Chicago suburbs.

Comment: This topic is already very well covered on the internet. Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-efficient_driving

Comment: It should be noted that implicit in this question is that this is for internal combustion engine vehicles.  The answer does change a little bit in an electric car, for multiple reasons.

Comment: You could get a [bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

Comment: Not mentioned among the answers, but what I am curious about myself is: is there anything we can do by altering the car to make it more fuel efficient? Anything I can ask the garage owner to do, for example?

Answer (score 15):

Several factors come to mind

- **Air-conditioning**
  Probably one of the bigger factors for saving fuel. At low speeds, open the windows instead (if it's hot); close the windows & wear a jacket (when it's cold). For high speed, close the windows, even when it's hot. At higher speeds the drag created by open windows uses more fuel than the air-conditioning. (See comment by Jay Bazuzi & [reference](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/the_green_lantern/2010/08/natures_air_conditioner.html) by walker below.)
- **Air pressure of your tyres**
  Not the biggest factor, but you decrease wear (long-term benefit) and friction, which saves fuel on the day, so to speak (short-term benefit).
- **"Defensive" (anticipatory) driving**
  ... meaning try to drive without having to step on the brakes. Keep your distance from the cars in front of you. Take your foot of the gas when the traffic light turned to red. (But remember, braking is more cost-efficient than having an accident. Safety comes first, also for sustainability.)
- **Avoid traffic**
  Like the point above, avoid traffic, because in traffic you'll have to brake (for other cars, cyclists, children, traffic lights), which is necessary, but not fuel efficient. Scheduling a longer route around town may well be more efficient (esp. if you are driving defensively and slowly) and doesn't drive you up the wall. (You said that already, I know.)
- **Reduce weight**
  No reason to drive around with unnecessary heavy objects in your trunk. Only take with you what you need.
- **Drive slowly**
  Driving twice as fast increases the air resistance 4-fold. Driving faster thus necessarily means you use more fuel for the same distance. (I mean, don't drive faster than everyone else, not drive slower than everyone else, forcing people to have to wait for you. That will result in aggression and risky overtaking manoeuvres of other people, using more net fuel...)
- **Make your car aerodynamic**
  Don't transport anything on the roof (if possible). The air resistance is very high. If you do, drive slowly. (See "Drive slowly")
- **Don't accelerate too fast**
  Give your cylinders a chance to use all the fuel you give to them efficiently. Accelerating too fast results in incomplete combustion and more fuel being used for nothing.

And a few obvious ones (for sake of completeness)

- **Form alliances**
  Take your neighbours to the shopping mall and they'll return the favour.
- **Only drive when necessary**
  You save the most fuel when you don't drive at all. Take the bus or train or hitch a ride with friends or neighbours.

Comment: Driving with the windows open creates drag. It varies with speed & vehicle, but on the highway you're usually better off using the A/C than opening windows.

Comment: The term "defensive driving" already means "drive to avoid accidents"; let's not add new meanings.

Comment: Driving slowly has two negative consequences: it pisses off other people (creating a field of negative energy or whatever) and motivates them to drive more aggressively (consuming more fuel, offsetting your usage). Obviously, if you're the only one on the road, it's no big deal.

Comment: Re: defensive driving. I guess I extended the usual meaning of "driving to avoid accidents". But also for driving without brakes, one needs to look ahead anticipate the movements of others... Any better name, then? Re: driving slowly. I meant of course, "don't drive faster than everybody else, if not necessary" rather than "drive slower than everybody else"...

Comment: @Jay - hypermilers and folks like the Institute of Advanced Motorists do use Defensive Driving to include anticipatory and aware driving

Comment: @JayBazuzi - There is a [question about this over at skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5661) sadly the best evidence I could find was from [mythbusters](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5723) which suggested that for **their vehicle** *"Going less than 50mph it is more efficient to leave your windows down, but going greater than 50mph it is more efficient to use your A/C."*

Comment: Driving faster **does not** necessarily mean that you are going to use more fuel. I challenge anyone to get on motorway, and go 10 mph, and then report what kind of mileage they would get.

Comment: Or try driving at 0 mph and report your mileage... I was thinking of the people who drive 150 mph on the German highway. Surely you agree that this way of driving uses more fuel.

Comment: Re: air-conditioning: This [Slate article](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/the_green_lantern/2010/08/natures_air_conditioner.html) references a 2004 study by the Society of Automotive Engineers and concludes this rule of thumb: in city streets keep the windows down (and A/C off), on highways keep the windows up, and use A/C if desired.

Comment: @theUg, theoretically, driving faster *would* necessarily mean that you use more fuel, as wind drag goes with the airspeed squared (EVs do behave this way).  However, internal combustion engines have a specific property that they have a significant efficiency peak, at a certain rotational speed (rpm).  Automakers have designed transmissions such that the engine's peak efficiency will occur at a groundspeed that's somewhere in the middle of a normal range.  Therefore, the net effect is that efficiency is bad at very low speeds, gets a bit better at medium speeds, and falls again at high speeds.

Comment: @Nate, that is what I implied. I simply took an issue with an irresponsible statement. Theoretically, indeed, the vehicle with only a final drive (no gearbox), and flat power curve (such as direct electric drive) would experience more drag with increase of velocity. However, as you’ve said, ICE are endowed with complex and uneven combination of power delivery and torque across the RPM band, and that is why effective use of gears provides higher benefit while the effects of drag are negligible in comparison. Hence, my statement stands, at least as it pertains to the vast majority of vehicles.

Comment: Regarding winter driving: as far as I know the heating is provided by the engine cooling system, therefore doesn't consume more energy than just the fan.

Comment: @clabacchio: that's true only as long as long as you do not use more heat than is excessive heat that otherwise need to be get rid of by the cooling. Even in mild German winters we easily have conditions where this is not the case with modern fuel saving combustion engines. Quite some cars actually have an additional *heater* (which burns fuel) that kicks in to avoid the motor getting cold / warming only slowly due to heating being turned on.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica well I'm used to a mild climate, and my car is not provided with Webasto or similar, so I didn't think about that possibility :) I just get cold air out of the outlets when the car is cold

Comment: @clabacchio: If turning on the heater has the effect that the engine takes longer to reach working temp or even goes permanently below normal working temperature, you'll have worse fuel economy (the cars I'm familiar with will always provide heating according to water temperature - i.e. they don't shut off the heating for motor/water temp below warm working conditions). (I'd also call my climate mild - but we do reach such conditions)

Answer (score 11):

### Driving Strategies

I did some research and personal experimentation on the topic, and here are some findings (more information in attached links). To achieve better mileage I would advocate the **appropriate driving**. The term *defensive driving* relates to proactive risk management of on-road hazards, and can be done regardless of speed and acceleration.

Arbitrary “slower speed” does not guarantee better fuel economy, as different vehicles have different optimal RPM range for any given gear (with highest gear being most economical). However, at motorway speeds aerodynamic drag plays ever increasing role, and that optimal RPM range is usually allows for lower speed than most people indulge themselves on the autobahn.

As a general rule, smooth acceleration and aptly timed deceleration is key, but there are instances where it does not hold true. For example if one pulls out of side street during a rush hour, and the choice is to accelerate rapidly to safely merge into traffic, or be faced with the long line of cars and couple of minutes of idling, the winner is clearly the former (more on evils of idling later).

Proper deceleration is important, because fast braking (even if one “drives defensively” well under speed limit) does nothing but converting kinetic energy into waste heat, whereas there are more efficient ways to slow down. Releasing throttle well ahead of time not only reduces wear of brake pads and tyres, but allows the car to use natural losses of energy (inside the engine and drivetrain, aerodynamic drag etc.) to slow itself down. Importantly, it has to be done in gear ([engine braking](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/is-engine-braking-harmful/3610#3610)) which qualifies as an *engine overrun* condition (throttle is off and RPMs are higher than idle) at which point ECU on modern fuel-injected petrol motors *shuts off fuel delivery entirely*.

It is possible to greatly reduce need for acceleration by planning ahead and properly timing the traffic signals, slowing down well ahead of red lights in order to roll onto green, or accelerating when needed to make the green light, to avoid idling on red.

### On Evils of Idling

The next big thing is **to reduce idling**. Besides the obvious “burning fuel with no miles” (0 MPG), there are more serious mechanical consideration against idling (even aforementioned fuel shut-off during overrun was primarily introduced to protect catalytic converter from incomplete combustion). Those are [enumerated elsewhere on SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/is-idling-bad-for-your-engine/3428#3428), but in short that incomplete combustion leads to reducing effectiveness of spark plugs (which, in turn, further reduces fuel economy), glazing of combustion chamber, contaminating of oil, and excessive amount of water in exhaust system which increases corrosion. Moreover, idling produces more pollution from the same amount of fuel. For those concerned about implication of frequent stopping and restarting the vehicle, there is some math in above link, and more [in another](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/825/is-start-stop-technology-good-or-bad-for-my-car-alfa-mito/3566#3566).

In practicality, this means turning off engine at long stop lights, railroad crossings, at the corner shop, and so forth, and reducing time spent warming up. Modern engines warm up better when they are put under moderate load rather than idling. And in the winter, one should protect the windscreen from defrosting with covered parking or putting blanket on it overnight, and to wear weather appropriate clothing, and not waiting for the car interior to turn into sauna.

### More Better

Other suggestions are also true: **proper tyre pressure** (also, safety issue, as under-inflated tyres are at risk of overheating failure), **low rolling resistance tyres** ([some concerns addressed](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/are-there-any-disadvantage-to-fuel-efficient-tires/3471#3471)), **diligent maintenance** (plugs, wires, oil and filters affect performance in little ways that can add up), and **removing unnecessary weight or aerodynamic impediments** (if you do not have skis or a bicycle on your roof rack, it has to go).

Outside of the mechanicals, **alternative transportation** (walking, biking, public transport, motorcycling) and **carpooling** can make an impact. Public transport generally takes longer time, but this time can be used more productively (reading, homework, work), one avoids traffic stress, parking costs, reduces wear, tear, and statistical possibility of an accident in own car. Also helps **avoiding rush hour** when possible, and **combining trips** (engine is more efficient at proper operating temperature, and many separate small trips do not allow motor to reach it).

Keeping track of the fuel usage (I use Fuelly, [personally](https://www.fuelly.com/driver/theUg)) helps not only for monitoring effects of any particular approach, but can also point to problems if certain negative trends develop.

The above is very sensible practises that many can readily apply today in improving their driving habits without entering arcane realm of hardcore *hypermiling*.

Comment: I agree with almost everything, except the part about using the engine to brake.  I think that's terrible advice in almost all situations (the exception being a very long downhill grade, where you have reason to believe that your brakes will overheat).  The brakes were designed to stop your car.  The engine and transmission were not.  The brake pads, and even rotors, are designed to be replaced easily, at modest cost.  Transmission ... not so much.  Stressing the transmission in reverse also activates mechanical stress in the opposite direction, which can have nonlinear fatigue implications.

Comment: @Nate, read the link provided about engine braking. The engine does not experience any additional stress compared to when it is under acceleration (if anything, the opposite, as there is no combustion in a modern FI motor). As for transmission, numerous patents pertaining to commercial driving stress the importance of engine braking over regular braking, and that is in the industry where heavily loaded gargantuan vehicles go on for over a million kilometres without a major overhaul.

Comment: As obsessed those people with reliability and maintenance cost, I am sure they would worry about transmission wear if it was the major factor in engine braking.

Comment: By the way, when driving properly and using regular brakes to slow down, one still has to do it in gear, and down-shift along the way, thus, effectively, combining regular and engine braking anyway. Simply disengaging transmission from 60 km/h, with, say, manual gearbox, and using brakes alone is not advised due to wear and safety concerns (the vehicle should be in proper gear at higher speeds in case acceleration in avoidance manoeuvre is required. Automatic transmissions give you a little choice, but to engine brake when using regular brakes.

Comment: The *link* about engine braking is another post by you.  Patents are descriptions of ideas, not peer-reviewed reporting of experimental results.  A patent's role is to carve out intellectual property.  An idea expressed in a patent need not be valid.  Commercial trucking is a completely different scenario from that which the OP asked about.  Commercial trucks are usually fleet vehicles, that are maintained.  The cost of transmission maintenance can be spread over lots of miles.  A new transmission for the OP is likely a prohibitive cost.

Comment: Also, the rationale behind engine braking on downhill grades (which I already mentioned an exception for) for trucks is entirely based on safety, not efficiency (maintenance cost, or fuel). Trucks going downhill are an even bigger safety risk for brake failure, so that totally makes sense. Again, totally different regime than that posed in the question.

Comment: Looking back at the question again, I notice that her car is an automatic, so I agree that you don't really have a choice how much engine braking is done.  I was responding to your answer, which sounded to be providing more *general* advice (applicable to stick drivers).  I certainly don't know many drivers of automatics who try to shift to neutral when decelerating.

Answer (score 7):

The existing answer is excellent but before you do any of that, **measure your fuel usage**.  If you don't measure what you're doing, you don't know if you're even making an improvement.

Some cars have a fuel efficiency gauge on the dash but I don't recommend watching this as you drive.  The times at which the greatest gains can be made (i.e. accelerating) are exactly the same times when the most concentration is required to ensure you don't crash.  Crashing is not fuel efficient.  If you have an efficiency gauge in your car, check it at the end of each journey, not while you are driving.

If you don't have one or even if you do, the tried and true method of *writing it down when you fill up on fuel* is my recommendation.  For years when I owned a car I kept a notepad in the glove box that contained pre-drawn columns:

```
_______________________________________________________________________
|Date    |Odometer    |Fuel quantity    |Fuel cost    |Notes           |
|        |            |                 |             |                |
|        |            |                 |             |                |
|        |            |                 |             |                |
```

From these values, you can calculate how far you traveled since the last fill-up and how much fuel you used to travel that distance and from that, what your *fuel efficiency* was.  The cost isn't necessary for calculating efficiency but I found that information interesting too.

Make sure to fill up consistently the same way each time.  This is usually achieved by simply holding the fuel pump trigger until it clicks off automatically.

You can also buy car travel logs with similar columns (they usually have both *Start odometer* and *End odometer* columns).  In this modern age of iPhones, Andriods and 3G, you can enter your travel details straight into websites designed to calculate your fuel efficiency such as [Fuelly](http://www.fuelly.com/) and [MPGTune](http://www.mpgtune.com/).

Once you have been recording your actual fuel usage for a while, start changing one of the above suggestions at a time and don't change anything else for several fill-ups.

---

I'd like to add a few notes from personal experience from when I went through improving my fuel efficiency.  I was driving a large 4WD so the fuel costs hurt.

The first two ideas I tried were what are called above **defensive driving** and **don't accelerate too fast**.  Leaving a large gap in front of me meant that often the traffic lights would go green before I even needed to brake, meaning I didn't need to accelerate again and waste fuel.  Accelerating slowly simply uses less fuel to reach the same speed (but takes longer) however in small city traffic, I would usually catch the people who accelerated off ahead of me at the next set of red lights so I didn't end up being late due to my changed driving style.

With these two techniques, I improved my *measured* fuel efficiency from 15L/100Km to 11L/100Km.  (That's roughly 15mpg up to 21mpg).

I didn't get to try any further ideas as I moved to London, sold my car and bought a bike.  The fuel efficiency of a bike is generally given to be [53 miles per burrito](https://www.missionbicycle.com/store/53-miles-burrito).

Comment: +1 for the helpful driving info and the bicycle fuel efficiency data. (I've got a 53 MPB sticker on my bike.)

Answer (score 6):

One of the core practices most hypermilers use that hasn't been mentioned yet is DWB - Driving Without Brakes.

At least with accelerating, you are increasing your kinetic energy so can use it. Every time you hit the brakes you dissipate energy as heat and cannot recover it (unless you have a kinetic energy recovery system...)

From [hypermiler.co.uk](http://www.hypermiler.co.uk/hypermiling/hypermiling-techniques) (and these guys really know what they are talking about), the top 5 tips are:

- Don’t drive
- Drive defensively, anticipating the road ahead.
- Drive without brakes (DWB)
- Slow down
- Coasting

Comment: What do you mean, it hasn’t been mentioned yet? I did. ;)

Comment: DWB takes it a fair bit further than just the coasting, which is what I assumed you were referring to...

Comment: I did not specify it directly, but here is the quote: “Proper deceleration is important, because fast braking (even if one “drives defensively” well under speed limit) does nothing but converting kinetic energy into waste heat, whereas there are more efficient ways to slow down.” I know, I wrote a lot of stuff. :)

Comment: "What do you mean, it hasn’t been mentioned yet? I did." So did I (under "Defensive driving")... =)